# How to get highest number from array sum JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to return different color for highest data result from array sum.

my JavaScript code:

```
const getColorByTreatment = (d) => {
            let color = ''
            let acc
            let dataValue = []
            let obj = {}

            if (props.forms[0].dataTreatment === 'highest data') {
                for (let i = 0; i < props.datas.length; i++) {
                    if (props.datas[i].kecamatanId === d) {
                        JSON.parse(props.datas[i].fieldDatas).forEach((field) => {
                            if (!props.datas[i].id) return;
                            acc = {
                                ...acc,
                                [props.datas[i].id]: (acc?.[props.datas[i].id] ?? 0) + (parseInt(field?.value) ?? 0),
                            };
                        });

                        console.log(acc);

                            console.log(Math.max(acc[i+1]) > Math.max(acc[i+1]));
                            if(Math.max(acc[i+1]) > Math.max(acc[i+1])){
                                color = '#FFEDA0'
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            return color
        }
```

console log result:

[image]

My expectation is the looping `if (props.datas[i].kecamatanId === d)` will stop when there is have highest number, and then return the color.

Comment: Do you want to get the highest value from an array?

Comment: in looping for, if found the highest value of the sum, and then looping stop to set color value

Comment: You got it man, to get highest value you need to loop all the items and then find the max in acc, that is what you wanted right

Comment: its return NaN if we directly Math.max(acc)